# Why does Henry Jones Jr. uses the nickname Indiana?

Tags: indiana-jones

As long as I remember the name is Henry Walton Jones Jr, but I have never read why the Indiana nickname.
Is there any background info of this?

Comment: IIRC the third movie mentions that Indiana was the name of the family dog. Let's see if somebody locates the source for that.

Comment: It would be interesting as well!

Comment: Real-world answer - Indiana was George Lucas' dog. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Indiana

Comment: I was expecting something like that

Comment: Glib answer: because "Indiana" sells more movie tickets and merchandise than "Henry".

Comment: the franchise would not work out without the Indiana thing? I don’t think so...but

Comment: I always thought it was a result of the complicated relationship with his distant father. He didn't want to constantly be under his fathers shadow by sharing the name "Henry" with the diminisher "Junior". So he chose to go by something, anything, else. Hence "Indiana" because of his beloved former dog.

Comment: lets says thats ok, but why to choose the name of a dog? Why dont Tiberius(=p), Cornelius or Joe? Jr. has a great complex!!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This final clip from The Last Crusade says it all.

> I got a lot of fond memories of that dog.

### Conjecture

At the beginning of the movie we see *Indiana* Jones as a teenager, and his fellow scout calls him 'Indiana.' So perhaps as an assumed only child with a strict father his best friend was his dog Indiana, and when it passed away, he decided the best way to remember it was to take the name for himself.

### Fact

Indiana Jones likes dates.

Comment: Or maybe he liked the way his father treated Indiana (the dog) better than the way he treated him as Junior, so he wanted to be treated as Indiana.

Comment: @Bergi well, he does go fetch a lot (of artifacts) ^^ (which probably doubles as a subconscious way to also be better loved by his "obsessed with ancient history and artifacts"  father....)

Comment: Does it answer the question, why is he using this nickname? I got fond memories of my pets and I don't use their names. In addition, as a teenager in the beginning of the Last Crusade, he's already called Indiana by his friend, and the dog is still alive.

Comment: @Neow That must have been a confusing household, where the kid and the dog are called the same. Yeah, maybe the dad never called Junior by his 'self-chosen' pet name (pun intended), but what about his friends? If Junior brought the dog along when hanging out, and someone yelled "Indiana!", both would respond. That image is somehow funny, now that I think about it.

Comment: @OlivierDulac dogs fetch stuff too :p

Comment: @Jorrit well, that was the intended pun

Comment: Are there any clues here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Young_Indiana_Jones_Chronicles

Comment: Well, of course you'd expect an archaeologist to like dates - oh, wait, you meant like the fruit, preferably non-poisoned.

Comment: Then its a pun intended by Henry Jones Senior? He dislike his own son?

Comment: @riccs_0x No, Jr. chose the nickname 'Indiana' for himself, after the dog. His father called him 'Junior.' [Which Indiana did not like](https://youtu.be/VbUlktBPQps?t=3m43s).